# Fitting model to this data in R?

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to predict the crop yield. I tried multiple regression with this dataset. The summary would be 
[image]

I know the $p$-values are more than 0.05 and say it to drop it. But I need the variable. I am a novice to statistics and don't have much idea about it. Can anybody say what equation would fit into this data?

Comment: You may want to try `mod <- lm(Sugarcane ~ Rainfall * Area * MSP)`.  While the individual factors may not be statistically significant, it is possible that their interactions (found with `*` instead of `+`) may be significant.  Currently, with your Adjusted R-squared, your model is not explaining much.

Comment: Is this really all data you have? Because (i) I don't think you should assume linearity and (ii) if you want to predict you need to validate the model.

Answer (score 1):

I think no one here can tell you what model would fit the best on your data, for the simple reason that we do not know the data.

However, I can suggest that you should not try to find a model that tells you what you want to (small p-values for coeff of rainfall), instead considering both theory and econometrics you need to find the model that best describes your dependent variable. You must have clear in mind why your model could be biased and tackle these problems with the appropriate techniques.

Moreover, from your question, is not clear what you want to model. Few questions arise in my mind:

1. Why don't you include socio-economics information about households/farmers? (omitted variable bias)
2. Is sugarcane prevalently rainfed or irrigated? (omitted variable bias)
3. Information on fertilizers and other inputs are missing from your model and may be correlated with level of rainfall (omitted variable bias).
4. What is the spatial precision of the variable rainfall? (measurement errors?)
5. Don't you think that makes more sense to consider variation in rainfall (compared to the past long-term seasonal average)? Moreover, if you do not have information about agricultural inputs, variation in rainfall is less likely to be correlated with the latter.
6. If you DV is crop yield (output per unit cultivated area), you may pay more attention at including the variable "Area" as a regressor. Is "Area" the total land cultivated by an individual farmer? If this is the case, it would capture the scale-economy effects. However, it is likely that this variable brings multicollinearity in your model (please compute the VIF).

R squared: I would not pay much attention on that (on this stage), and by the way, 0.26 is an acceptable value.

Interactions and multiple testing: Before having a solid model it is highly recommended to avoid any multiple test or interaction unless previous studies/theory suggest that interaction effects are in place for your specific case.  If you try random specifications it is likely that sooner or later you find some statistical significant result. In this conduct lies the difference between those who dig for results and real researchers. It is a matter of intelectual honesty.

You should look up at the existing literature to build your model. [Here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378377499000530), you find an article that (I believe) does something close to what you want to model.